# process.standardoutput.ReadToEnd always empty

Tags: c#

I'm trying to run a command and get the output to a string so I can search the string to detect if a certain result happened.
The output written to console is just fine
...
(bootloader) 1
OKAY [  0.028s]
finished. total time: 0.028s

However, the string result is always an empty line. I tried getting it to output errors too, but that just results in nothing printing onto the console.
I also tried this code from a similar question

```
var output = new StringBuilder();
var error = new StringBuilder();

cmd.OutputDataReceived += (o, e) => output.Append(e.Data);
cmd.ErrorDataReceived += (o, e) => error.Append(e.Data);

cmd.Start();
cmd.BeginOutputReadLine();
cmd.BeginErrorReadLine();
cmd.WaitForExit();
```

Which caused nothing to be outputted because Output StandardError was there, removing it just caused the same problem as original. I've tried numerous other things from almost any question on here I could find, but to no avail. Someone please help.

Here's my code:

```
ProcessStartInfo unlkinfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C 
fastboot flashing get_unlock_ability");
unlkinfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
unlkinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
unlkinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Process unlk= new Process();
unlk.StartInfo = unlkinfo;
unlk.Start();
String result = unlk.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
unlk.WaitForExit();
String BL1 = "(bootloader) 1";
if(result.Contains(BL1))
{
Console.WriteLine("Bootloader is unlocked!");
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine("Bootloader is locked!");
}
```

Comment: What is the actual content of your result?

Comment: It just prints a blank line

Comment: the same code works well for other commands like `/C hostname`, seems like the problem not in the code, but in the `fastboot` command execution, check other options